# Customer/Client specific code with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

in a project we have several customers/clients for a Rails 3 application, where some of them need specific code although we try to solve as many requirements as possible through configuration of the application.

We want to have all customer code in a single branch but in separate directories. Therefore I am now experimenting with `autoload_paths`:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('customer', 'abc', 'app', 'models')]
```

This works for new files/classes/models, but it is not possible to modify existing models/classes with this approach. For example I want to add a single method to `app/models/test_model.rb` from `customer/abc/app/models/test_model.rb`:

```
class TestModel
  def self.test_me; 123; end
end
```

Unfortunately this overrides the whole class/model and not only this single method. I know that I can do this in Ruby even for core classes like `String`:

```
class String
  def to_bla; "bla"; end
end
```

Is it possible to have this behavior also for rails models or is there any better way to separate customer specific code from the rest of the project? I would prefer a solution where I don't have to insert `require`s or `include`s in the files I want to customize. It would also be great when rails automatically reloads files for changes in customer specific files in development mode.

Comment: just require base file in your customized file.